# Whats the code for this surfaceplot?

Tags: plotting

Does anybody know the code to plot the following picture:
[image]

Having trouble to come up with a good idea...

Comment: What you can do to increase the quality of the question is to give any relevant information about the surface, equations, papers, etc., instead of just gimme_teh_codez

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "here is an image of what I want, please give me the code to generate it"-type of questions probably won't help future visitors.

Answer (score 8):

I'll leave the mesh lines and the coloring up to somebody else:

```
With[{c = 3, a = 1, n = 9, r = 1/3}, 
     ParametricPlot3D[{{c Cos[u], c Sin[u], 0},
                       {(c + a Cos[n u]) Cos[u], (c + a Cos[n u]) Sin[u], a Sin[n u]}},
                      {u, 0, 2 π}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#4/(2 π)] &), 
                      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}, 
                      PlotRange -> All] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, r, rest]]
```

[image: torus spiral and torus]